# Database set cell to NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have the following table structure:

```
Inventory: userid - a - b - c - d - e - f - g - h - i - j - k
```

The letters represent an inventory's slots. Here are stored *products*' ids. These products' data are also stored in a table called `Products`. The values in `Inventory` are linked to the `id` of the item in `Products`

A user wants to throw a product from his inventory, clicks a button and using ajax the `id` of the item is sent to the server.

How can I find and set to NULL the cell containing that product if I have no information other information than the id?

P.S. I am using Symfony framework, if this makes the things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, just an idea:

```
UPDATE Inventory SET a = NULL WHERE a = id AND userid=uid;
UPDATE Inventory SET b = NULL WHERE b = id AND userid=uid;
...
UPDATE Inventory SET k = NULL WHERE k = id AND userid=uid;
```

This one should work, but I cannot run it to test:

```
UPDATE Inventory 
SET 
 a = CASE WHEN a=id THEN NULL ELSE a END,
 b = CASE WHEN b=id THEN NULL ELSE b END,
 c = CASE WHEN c=id THEN NULL ELSE c END,
 d = CASE WHEN d=id THEN NULL ELSE d END,
 e = CASE WHEN e=id THEN NULL ELSE e END,
 f = CASE WHEN f=id THEN NULL ELSE f END,
 g = CASE WHEN g=id THEN NULL ELSE g END,
 h = CASE WHEN h=id THEN NULL ELSE h END,
 i = CASE WHEN i=id THEN NULL ELSE i END,
 j = CASE WHEN j=id THEN NULL ELSE j END,
 k = CASE WHEN k=id THEN NULL ELSE k END
WHERE userid=uid;
```

Comment: I think it's the best solution; but it is horrible. Rovinari have you considered altering your table so you don't have to do things like this? At the very least it should be unique on user id and product id.

Comment: @Ben: you're right, it's horrible, I know :( I think second syntax is _"a quite good solution"_ (if it works), but table design doesn't help...

Comment: @Ben Userid and product id are definitely unique. How can I correct this table structure to make things easier?

Comment: @Rovinari: You could have this table: userid - slot_id - product_id. So, for a single user, you'll have 11 rows (one for every slot from _a_ to _k_), where slot_id is an INT. Removing an item becomes easy: `UPDATE Inventory SET product_id=NULL WHERE user_id=uid AND product_id=id;`

Comment: I haven't thought of this possibility. Thanks again.